# Две фразы, каждая с подлежащим и сказуемым, соподчинённые третьей фразе — пунктуация

Tags: запятые, спп

> *Гектор, герой Трои, побеждал самых храбрых из греков, но мужество ему **изменило,** и он обратился в бегство, когда перед ним предстал Ахилл.*

Если я правильно понимаю, мы видим ССП, вторая часть которого начинается с НО. Она представляет собой СПП, из которого, если отбросить придаточное с *"когда",* получилось бы ещё одно ССП. Но при наличии придаточной части каждая из этих потенциальных сложносочинённых частей (начинаются с НО и И) ***подчинена ей*** (придаточной части с *"когда").*

Возникает вопрос: *правильно ли стоит выделенная **запятая** между потенциальными СС частями, и какое вообще для такого случая действует правило?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(1) Гектор, герой Трои, побеждал самых храбрых из греков, но (2) мужество ему изменило и (3) он обратился в бегство, когда (4) перед ним предстал Ахилл.*

1) Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной союзной связью. **Союз НО делит его на два блока**.  Во второй блок входят три простых предложения. Между предложениями 2 и 3 сочинительная связь с помощью союза И, но запятая не ставится, так как эти предложения имеют общее придаточное.

Пример из Розенталя: *Но Лёля спала так спокойно и в её ресницах, казалось, роились такие хорошие сны, что Наталья Петровна не решилась разбудить дочь* (Пауст.).

2) Почему же стоит запятая? Можно предположить, что ошибочно использовано правило Розенталя относительно **союза НО:**

**Противительный союз,** после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом И простых предложения, **общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед И ставится:**  *Он подавил вздох и не спеша стал сворачивать папироску, **но** почему-то дрогнули руки, и он рассыпал на колени табак* (Ш.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Но в нашем случае общим элементом является не союз НО, а придаточное.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! За другие примеры и особенно за то, что Вы постарались объяснить возможную **причину** такой ошибки! Очень интересно!

Answer (score 0):

Общее придаточное, запятой между главными нет.

Comment: Она в книжке стоит (в сноске), ошибка?

Comment: Должно быть, да.